# python date with different length and extract year information

Tags: python, date

I have dates where `117/12/31` means `17/12/31`. How can I extract the year `17` and change it to year `2017`? For dates before `2000`, the format is (e.g.) `89/12/31`. In this case I need to get the year format as `1989`.

Comment: Is your date a string? Looks like some simple regex should so the trick.

Comment: `import datetime`?

Comment: @JacobIRR `datetime` doesn't know how to handle 3-digit "YY overflow" years like this. (I think the third-party `dateutil` does, but I'm not positive.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me your dates have year `1900` as the base year, due to which `1989` is represented as `89` and `2017` is represented as `117`. So, I would just add `1900` to the year portion to get the actual year of the date:

```
>>> s = "117/12/31"
>>> int(s.split("/")[0]) + 1900
2017
>>> s = "89/12/31"
>>> int(s.split("/")[0]) + 1900
1989
```

Answer (score 0):

You could regex your way through:

```
import re

s = "117/12/31"
a = re.match(r'(\d{2,3})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})', s)
year = int(a.group(1))

if (year > 100):
    print "Year is 20%d" % (year - 100)
else:
    print "Year is 19%d" % year
```

Prints:

```
Year is 2017
```